# Adding blank line (between) and indenting first line of all paragraphs

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I would like to have a blank line between all the paragraphs in addition to the indent on the first line of the paragraph (instead of *just* the indent).

As of now I am using the following to add just a line between all the paragraphs

```
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

I am using the `book` class.

How do I achieve the first line indent *and* a blank line between each paragraph?

Comment: Just do `\parindent20pt` after loading the package.  If you don't want to hardcode 20pt but instead prefer to "do what book.cls does by default", you need to save the default before it gets set to 0: try something like `\edef\mindent{\theparindent}\usepackage[...]{...}\parindent\mindent`.  There may be a better way to do this, but that's for someone who knows more than me to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use the `indentfirst` for indent the first paragraph after a chapter or section title.
2. Set `\parskip` to fix the space between paragraphs. Better that some fixed length like `2ex` use a stretchable glue like `2ex plus .2ex minus .1ex` to allow some stretch when needed. Experiment to find the best results for you.
3. Set  `\parindent` (note that this lenght is not stretchable).

If you still need the `parskip` package for control list spacing, be sure of load the package ***before*** of these settings.

```
\documentclass{book}
% \usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % load me before !
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength\parskip{.5\baselineskip plus .1\baselineskip  minus .1\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The Chapter}
\lipsum[1-14]   
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Note that some people recommend either the indentation or the paragraph spacing, but not both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I don't need the first paragraph after a section or a chapter to be indented. So I just left out the `indentfirst` package. And I agree on the use just one of them recommendation as well, but I need to do this since my University mandates it. 
I'll just wait a day more and then accept the answer. :)